# How can I display a very high resolution panorama online?

Tags: web, image-stitching

I recently created a very high resolution panorama from 20x stitched images.

I want to be able to share the image online so that people can explore the detail.

Gigapan used to be able to do this but has stopped trading - Are there any platforms available to do this? I could also self-host but would need some sort of "player" to embed to do this (I do not use wordpress)

[image: Low res - Derbyshire hills]

Comment: You can check (and wait) for zoomhub. Ig you have programming skill you can try to implement it on your own site: https://github.com/zoomhub/zoomhub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pannellum](https://pannellum.org/) can do exactly this, especially since you mention you are willing to self-host. The project is well-documented with sample code snippets and reference materials for each feature.

It also has a [multi-resolution feature](https://pannellum.org/documentation/examples/multiresolution/) for very large images, to make viewing them more practical.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that looks absolutely spot-on for my needs! Ill be sure to post a link once I've had a play :-)